# Get the value of clicked text box from array of text boxes using PHP

Tags: php

i want to get the text box value which i selected from array of text boxes..
My code is like this:

Here am displaying the data on the browser from DB..

```
<?php
foreach($dataDecoded['categories'] as $key => $value)
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $value['CategoryName'];?></td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="categoryId[]" id="categoryId" value="<?php echo $value['CategoryId']?>">
<input type="text" name="categoryName[]" id="categoryName" value="<?php echo $value['CategoryName']?>">
<input type="submit" name="create" id="create" value="create">
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

The data will be displayed like:

```
categoryId1     categoryName1    <Create Button>

categoryId2     categoryName2    <Create Button>

categoryId3     categoryName3    <Create Button>

and so on like this..
```

Now, suppose When i click on Create Button of `CategoryName2`, i want to get the `categoryId` and `categoryName` of only `CategoryName2`..

Am using this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['create']) && $_POST['create']=="create")
{
    $cat_id[]=$_POST['categoryId'];
    $cat_name[]=$_POST['categoryName'];
}
```

But with this, am getting all the `categoryId` and `categoryName` into the array.. how to get only the selected textbox value..

I want to do it using only PHP and not with JavaScript / JQuery... Am a bit new to PHP... Can someone help me / give me a suggestion about how to do it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just create a form for each category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each one in its own form:

```
<td>
    <form method="POST" action="somePage.php">
        <input type="text" name="categoryId" value="<?php echo $value['CategoryId']?>">
        <input type="text" name="categoryName" value="<?php echo $value['CategoryName']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="create" value="create">
    </form>
</td>
```

Since the content being posted in this case is just these two values, then that's the entire scope of a single form post.  So each one is logically/semantically its own form.  (There's no rule that says a page can have only one form.  Unless you're ever using ASP.NET WebForms, which is a lie.)

Note also that I removed your `id` attributes.  Multiple elements can't have the same `id`, that's invalid HTML and any behavior as a result becomes undefined.

Comment: But i have around 2000 categories in my DB.. won't  the code be heavy if i do so ???

Comment: @phpfresher: Having 2000 of *anything* on a single webpage is probably a less than ideal UX, you might look into something more dynamic than that.  But what makes you think one extra element per item is going to make a huge difference?  You already have 6 HTML elements per category, is 7 really going to be a problem?

Comment: Thank You.. It worked for me... :)
I'll go with it...
But is there any other solution other than taking one form for each `category` ??
coz, if in some other place i have the same problem with some lakhs of records, it'll be a problem there naa.. :)

Comment: @phpfresher: Another approach (which I haven't tried, but it might work) could be to set the `value` of the `submit` button to the Category ID.  Even though the entire form is submitted, I *think* only the *clicked* submit button is included in the form values.  Though even if that works, it's unnecessary overhead to submit *thousands of values* when you only need *one* value.  You're worrying too much about the in-browser performance and sacrificing API performance as a result.  A few more lines of code won't hurt anything if the code logically makes more sense.

Comment: okkk.. thank you.. :-)
I've wasted my whole day for this code.. It makes me laugh when i think i wasted my whole day for only 7 lines of code.. hahahahaa...